# Counting child NSDictionary keys

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdictionary, enumeration

I'm trying to count the number of dictionary keys within an `NSDictionary` dictionary's dictionary but am coming up empty. The values I would like to count are how many dictionaries are in those of the dictionary `SubDict`, which are in each dictionary `Dict1`, `Dict2`, `Dict3`, which are part of dictionary `theDict` - in the example below it should total `9`. How would I properly count the children's children dictionary's keys?

Here's the code I've used with the `NSDictionary` structure.

```
NSDictionary *keyCount = [theDict objectForKey:@"SubDict"];
NSUInteger count = [[keyCount allKeys] count];

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long) count);
```

It returns the value 0.

```
Dict1 =     {
    SubDict =         {
        1 = data;
        2 = data;
        3 = data;
        4 = data;
    };
};
Dict2 =     {
    SubDict =         {
        1 = data;
        2 = data;
    };
};
Dict3 =     {
    SubDict =         {
        1 = data;
        2 = data;
        3 = data;
    };
}; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `theDict` looks like this, then there is no key in `theDict` for "SubDict". Instead there are four child dictionaries, each of which has one child. So you need to accumulate the count of each one:

```
int count = 0;
for (NSDictionary * dict in theDict.allValues) {
    count += [[dict objectForKey:"SubDict"] count];
}
NSLog(@"total items: %d", count);
```